# Data validation List with Formula as source

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

I'm trying to create a dropdown list with a formula to filter what gets in the list but I get an error.

Here's the formula used: =IF(Sheet1!$C$1:$C$7="Yes",Sheet1$A$1:$A$7,"")

Comment: That would be an array formula and Data Validation does not allow array formula.  You will need to use helper cells to hold the array formula then refer to the range of the helper cells.

Answer (score 0):

Formulas are not allowed in the source field. As @Scott said, you need helper cells.

When making dynamic lists, I would recommend you use the spill range operator instead of referencing the range directly. With a direct reference, empty cells show up as blanks. With a dynamic reference they can be removed.

For example, your formula may be in cell `D1`. The formula can be modified to `=FILTER(A1:A7,C1:C7="yes","-")`. The list source would then be `D1#`.

Comment: Excel *does* allow some restricted formulas in *Data Validation » List » Source*.  For example, `IF(A1="f", $F$1:$F$20, $G$1:$G$20)` *is* allowed.  The only documentation I can find is (indirectly) by way of this error message:  *“You may not use reference operators (such as unions, intersections, and ranges), array constants, or the LAMBDA function for Data Validation criteria.”*  That comes up if I enter `={"A";"B";"C"}` (for example).  For other (otherwise valid) functions that are (evidently) not allowed, it just says *“The Source currently evaluates to an error. Do you want to continue?”*